# Pure Math Research into Operator Fields

Tags: operator-theory, vector-fields

Has any work been done on operator fields in the pure math world? They are a big piece of quantum field theory, but I can't find anything about them outside of that messy subject. Of course, I mean "fields" in the physics sense.

The best I could find was this: [http://www.amazon.com/Theory-Operator-Fields-HAWAII-HONOLULU/dp/B009TIRYRQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009TIRYRQ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to learn more about operator fields in the sense of physics, then I recommend Wolfhart Zimmermann’s papers on composite operators and the operator product expansion (OPE). Let me provide two references:

- K. Wilson, W. Zimmermann, [*Operator Product Expansions and Composite Field Operators in the General Framework of Quantum Field Theory*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01878448), Communications in Mathematical Physics, Volume 24, Issue 2 (1972), pp. 87-106.
- W. Zimmermann, [*Local Operator Products and Renormalization in Quantum Field Theory*](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/lectures-elementary-particles-and-quantum-field-theory), Lectures on Elementary Particles and Quantum Field Theory, Proceedings of the 1970 Brandeis Summer Institute in Theoretical Physics, S. Deser et al. (Eds.), MIT Press, Cambridge, MA, pp. 399-589.

Zimmermann is the inventor of the **Zimmermann Forest Formula** in the Bogoliubov-Parasiuk-Hepp-Zimmermann (BPHZ) Renormalization Scheme, which is a method of subtracting the pesky infinities in divergent Feynman amplitudes in a combinatorial fashion.

John Collins has written a book entitled *Renormalization*, published by the Cambridge University Press. It treats the theory of operator fields in a mathematically respectable manner, so you should check it out.

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify, I specified "in the physics sense" to distinguish between physical fields (i.e., vector fields) and mathematical fields (i.e., the field of rational numbers.)

Comment: I get what you mean now. I don’t think there’s something called an ‘operator field’ in the algebraic sense. As you have already mentioned, in mathematics, the word ‘field’ has two different meanings.

Comment: Now, there’s something called a ‘[continuous field of $ C^{\ast} $-algebras](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/continuous+field+of+C*-algebras)’. By the Gelfand-Segal-Naimark (GNS) Construction, every $ C^{\ast} $-algebra can be viewed as an operator-norm-closed $ \ast $-subalgebra of $ \mathscr{B}(\mathcal{H}) $ for some Hilbert space $ \mathcal{H} $. A cross-section of this continuous field might reasonably be called a ‘field of operators’.

Comment: Thanks for the book suggestions. Now that you know what I mean, do you happen to know of any other pure math treatments of operator physical fields?